# Unable to use variable defined inside if statement

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do something like this in android:

```
// If the parent is a viewpager
if (parentIsViewPager)
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations specific to viewpagers
    ViewPager.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = (ViewPager.MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
}
// If the parent is not a viewpager (mainly a viewgroup)
else
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations for a viewgroup
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = getLayoutParams();
}

Log.i("Test","marginLayoutParams.leftMargin = " + marginLayoutParams.leftMargin);
```

Unfortunately, the IDE (Android Studio 1.5.1) tells me it cannot find declaration for layoutParams in the last line above... But I declared it in the if statements!

I guess there is something about scope in here but as the following code in my project is really big, I cannot duplicate it in each if statement.

So how can I achieve this or something similar?

**EDIT:**
As I guessed, and this was confirmed in the comments, this is a matter of scope. Ok, got it.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable declaration is limited to it's scope.
In this case the if-else statement.

You could do it like this:

```
// Declare in correct scope and define later...
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams;

// If the parent is a viewpager
if (parentIsViewPager)
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations specific to viewpagers
    layoutParams = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
}
// If the parent is not a viewpager (mainly a viewgroup)
else
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations for a viewgroup
    layoutParams = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
}

Log.i("Test","layoutParams.width = " + layoutParams.width);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I guessed, but I cannot do it like that as the layoutParams is not from the same classes in my if statement. What you wrote gave me a runtime error as `ViewPager.LayoutParams` is different from `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` despite the fact the `ViewPager` is derived form `ViewGroup` (thanks Google!).

Comment: If you only need the methods declared in ViewGroup.LayoutParams class then use ViewGroup.LayoutParams. I fixed the code above.

Comment: Hehe! Nope! This rises an incompatible type conversion! This is why I needed the if statement... and why I thanked Google above lol. I though it will be that easy too as they are derived from each other, but nope... Too easy! We need challenges in our lives, right?!

Comment: What kind of incompatible type conversion and where? It should be possible to cast a derived class to it's super class...

Comment: Oups my bad I confused `LayoutParams` with `MarginLayoutParams`! I'm so sorry, but the problem is real, simply replace LayoutParams by MarginLayoutParams in my question... I will edit my OP.

Answer (score 1):

This compilation error has nothing to do with android or the IDE, is just the following:

```
if (parentIsViewPager)
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations specific to viewpagers
    ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewPager.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
}
```

in this condition, the "Variable" layoutParams has a Scope: only inside the if condition, 
the second part:

```
else
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations for a viewgroup
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
}
```

the same criteria applies..

the error is because you are trying to use an object out of its scope... 
layoutParams is not avaliable anymore outside that if condition

Comment: Yep it's what I guessed...   Thank you for the explanation. Do you have a solution to avoid this problem?

Comment: Yes, move the declaration over the if condition so the object can be "visible" inside that method, OR place it as a class variable....

Comment: I cannot move the declaration above the if statement as the variable is one class or another depending on the if statement... What do you mean by "place it as a class variable"? Do you mean a global variable inside the class? Unfortunately, the problem will be exactly the same...

Comment: A viewPager is an inherited class from the ViewGroup... so a there you have it

Comment: Well, see my other answers in comments, unfortunately, the 2 classes aren't compatible despite the fact they inherit from each other... I don't understand that neither...

Answer (score 1):

Is simply duplicating the Log statement on both sides of the if-else not an option or is layoutParams referenced else where?

```
// If the parent is a viewpager
if (parentIsViewPager)
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations specific to viewpagers
    ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewPager.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    Log.i("Test","layoutParams.width = " + layoutParams.width);
}
// If the parent is not a viewpager (mainly a viewgroup)
else
{
    // Retrieve the view's layout informations for a viewgroup
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
    Log.i("Test","layoutParams.width = " + layoutParams.width);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution. But as I wrote, my real code is really big after the if statement... So I would avoid it... Anyway, I edited my OP so take a look now and I will post the link in there in a few.